# Python - multiply range of column by last column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame in the following form

```
name v1 v2 v3
x    1  4  7
y    2  5  8
z    3  6  9
```

I want to multiply each value in the middle two columns by the value in the final column, output would be:

```
name v1 v2 v3
x    7  28  7
y    16 40  8
z    27 54  9
```

My current attempt is giving an error, Index object has no attribute apply

```
df[df.columns[1:-2]] = df.columns[1:-2].apply(lambda x : (x*df.columns[-1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting by position with [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:-1])
   v1  v2
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6

df.iloc[:, 1:-1] = df.iloc[:, 1:-1].mul(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0)
print (df)
  name  v1  v2  v3
0    x   7  28   7
1    y  16  40   8
2    z  27  54   9
```

Solution with selecting columns by names:

```
df[['v1','v2']] = df[['v1','v2']].mul(df['v3'], axis=0)
print (df)
  name  v1  v2  v3
0    x   7  28   7
1    y  16  40   8
2    z  27  54   9
```